# Video Streaming Using Spring Boot, Web Flux and Amazon S3 Not working Reactively from Backend to S3

Tags: java, spring-boot, amazon-s3, video-streaming, spring-webflux

I was developing code for a video streaming platform using Spring Boot, WebFlux, and AWS S3 for cloud storage. Although my code is streaming properly to the frontend from a local resource, it is not working as expected when streaming from the backend API to the S3 Bucket.

Instead of streaming it directly, it is retrieving the file from S3 and then streaming it. This is causing a major bottleneck in my app.

```
@Service
@Slf4j
public class StreamingService {

    private static final String FORMAT = "aws S3 bucket link";
    @Autowired
    private ResourceLoader resourceLoader;
    @Autowired
    private S3AsyncClient s3AsyncClient;
    @Autowired
    private S3ClientConfig s3ConfigProperties;

    // Stream from link
    public Mono<Resource> getVideos(String title) {
        return Mono.fromSupplier(() -> UrlResource.from(String.format(FORMAT, title)));
    }

    // Stream from object
    public Mono<byte[]> streamVideo(String title) {
        return Mono.just(GetObjectRequest.builder().bucket(s3ConfigProperties.getS3BucketName()).key(title + ".mp4").build())
                .map(it -> s3AsyncClient.getObject(it, AsyncResponseTransformer.toBytes()))
                .flatMap(Mono::fromFuture)
                .map(BytesWrapper::asByteArray);
    }

    // Store data in bytes then stream
    // It is good as it stream directly but fail for seeking opperation
    public Flux<DataBuffer> streamMp4FileFromS3(String title) {
        return DataBufferUtils.read(
                UrlResource.from(String.format(FORMAT, title)),
                new DefaultDataBufferFactory(),
                4096
        );
    }

}
```

Can someone explain how i can directly stream without storing mp4 file in loacal.

Comment: Do not use `BytesWrapper::asByteArray`

Comment: `BytesWrapper::asInputStream` and then manually writing content as response DataBuffer may help you

Comment: Not working, I tried it